# Copy specific cell value from all sheets which are available in the google drive and paste in master sheet with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have set of google sheets in my google drive and every week my client will post new google sheets in the same drive folder. Each google sheets will have 20 to 30 sheets. I need a data from the specific cell (A1) from all sheets, and paste in one specific master sheet to count the volume. Please guide me to creqte the required apps script.

Comment: What have you considered or tried? We can help if you have problems with something but we can't do all the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function countValue(){

var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Test").next();
var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
var rA=[];
while(spreadSheets.hasNext()){
var file=spreadSheets.next();
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
var shts=ss.getSheets();
for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++){
var Obj={ssname:file.getName() ,ssid:file.getId() ,shname:shts[i].getName() ,A1:shts[i].getRange('A1').getValue()};
rA.push(Obj);
}
}
var html="<table>";
html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><th>%s</th><th>%s</th><th>%s</th><th>%s</th><th>%s</th></tr>',"Item","Spreadsheet Name","Spreadsheet Id","Sheet Name","A1 Value");
for(var i=0;i<rA.length;i++){
html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',i+1,rA[i].ssname,rA[i].ssid,rA[i].shname,rA[i].A1);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
ss.getRange('A1').setValue(i);
return rA; 
}

};
```

Note : This is the revised script as per my requirement..

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a good start:

```
function getA1FromAllSheets(){
  var files=DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  var rA=[];
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var file=files.next();
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    var shts=ss.getSheets();
    for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++){
      var Obj={ssname:file.getName() ,ssid:file.getId() ,shname:shts[i].getName() ,A1:shts[i].getRange('A1').getValue()};
      rA.push(Obj);
    }
  }
  var html="<table>";
  html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><th>%s</th><th>%s</th><th>%s</th><th>%s</th><th>%s</th></tr>',"Item","Spreadsheet Name","Spreadsheet Id","Sheet Name","A1 Value");
  for(var i=0;i<rA.length;i++){
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',i+1,rA[i].ssname,rA[i].ssid,rA[i].shname,rA[i].A1);
  }
  html+='</table>';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'All the A1s in all the Sheets in all of Spreadsheet on Google Drive');
  return rA;
}
```

I suspect that this will take a long time to run because it's opening up a lot of files potentially.

Comment: Thank you so much Cooper... This apps script works perfectly..... I have just made few changes in the last line to get the value in the master sheet.....